# Un-Select JToggleButton

Tags: java, swing, jtogglebutton

I have a `JToggleButton`, not in a group, and if it's pressed, I want to be able to Un-Select
it if I press another `JButton`.

I've tried using:

```
toggleButton.setSelected(false);
toggleButton.doClick();
```

but neither un-Select the toggle button, it stays "highlighted".

What can I do so that the toggle button goes back to the normal
un-Selected state, like if I pressed it again?

Is it a matter of calling the above while in the UI Thread?

Comment: your question is not clear to me: `but neither un-Select the toggle button, it stays "highlighted".` what does this line mean ?

Comment: @Sage It means that they do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

**`jToggleButton.doClick()`**: Programmatically perform a "click". This does the same thing as if the user had pressed and released the button.

```
     jToggleButton1.setSelected(false);
        jToggleButton1.doClick();
```

If you execute this code subsequently, it is actually doing nothing. Because, as soon as the first line set the `jToggleButton1` as `unselected` second line set it as `selected`. If you want just `jToggleButton` to be unselected use `jToggleButton1.setSelected(false)` by removing `doClick()`. But if you want to toggle among selected and deselected using your other `JButton` click, use `jToggleButton1.doClick()` only.

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't use them together, I should have said that I tired each one, and neither worked. I just tried using doClick(), again and it looked like it worked.  Thanks